# Pass variables in fabricator gem and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fabrication-gem

How would I create a user by passing a variable used as a transient in rspec? What am I doing wrong?

controller_tests_spec.rb

```
describe "GET index" do
  context "with admin user_role" do
    before(:each) do
      set_current_admin
      todo_list1 = Fabricate(:todo_list)
      todo_list2 = Fabricate(:todo_list)
      get :index
    end
    it "redirects to the todo lists path" do
      expect(response).to redirect_to todo_lists_path
    end
  end
end
```

/support/macros.rb

```
def set_current_admin(user=nil)
  session[:user_id] = (user || Fabricate(:user, role: "admin")).id
end
```

Fabricators

```
  # user_fabricator.rb
  Fabricator(:user) do
    email {Faker::Internet.email}
    password 'password'
    first_name {Faker::Name.first_name}
    last_name {Faker::Name.last_name}
    transient :role  
    user_role {Fabricate(:user_role, role: :role)}
  end

  # user_role_fabricator.rb
  Fabricator(:user_role) do
    role
  end
```

Comment: Can you start by telling us what you observe that differs from what you expect? ie how do you know it's "going wrong" (because you haven't told us that yet), and what do you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All processed values (including transients) are available through the attrs hash passed into each field as it is fabricated. I modified your fabricators to do what I think you are expecting.

I defaulted the role field in `:user_role` to "member". The way you had it would try to expand to use another fabricator named `role`, which I don't think is what you want.

```
# user_fabricator.rb
Fabricator(:user) do
  email {Faker::Internet.email}
  password 'password'
  first_name {Faker::Name.first_name}
  last_name {Faker::Name.last_name}
  transient :role  
  user_role { |attrs| Fabricate(:user_role, role: attrs[:role]) }
end

# user_role_fabricator.rb
Fabricator(:user_role) do
  role 'member'
end
```